# Book about a cube prison that turns out to be a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, novel

I don't remember much about this book.

The main character is a girl, who trying to escape from this giant cube that she grew up in and that a bunch of people live in.

I think she is following a trail that was left by her mother? There was also something about a comb, I think.

I can remember it ends with her opening the "exit" and them being in space, resulting in her male friend being sucked out the airlock.

Comment: Can you add some more details? Such as when it was published, when you read it, what language, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is ***[Inside Out](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7059135-inside-out)*** by Maria V. Snyder (Chapter 1 [excerpt](http://www.mariavsnyder.com/books/InsideOut.php)).

The story is set in "Inside", the cube where they live.  It is a prison in the sense that they are trapped, not that they are convicts.  The main character is Trella, a girl who like other "scrubs" was brought up in a care facility by a Care Mother and never met her birth mother or father.

A male friend is killed by being sucked out of the airlock:

> Cog and Trella are looking for the legendary "Gateway" to take them "Outside" so when they go through the airlock's internal door and open its external door, without realising the danger, he is sucked out but he manages to save her (Chapter 20).  Only they do they (and the reader who hasn't guessed) find out that they are in a spaceship.

Trella has a comb "decorated with pink pearls along its spine. ... According to my CM it had been a gift from my birth mother." (Chapter 3) which has a minor role in the plot.

There are clues to solve in the form of hints for passwords needed to access documents that had been planted by Trella's birth mother.

The book has a sequel called *[Outside In](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8901953-outside-in)*.  Both books have been published together as *[Inside](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12548990-inside)*.

Answer (score -3):

Okay, this may or may not be it, but I figured I’d give it a shot since I **really** like the Cube series. In any event, is it possible that you are misremembering the movie? The reason I ask is because the cube series fit, or at least *they are very close*. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(film_series)

The premise of all three films is roughly the same – a bunch of people lose their memories and wind up alone in a room. This room is connected to other rooms (possibly upward of 100 or so) and the individuals meet up with each other. Some of the rooms have traps in them – ranging from the generic poison gas to the bizarre, a room where time accelerates to such an extent that the occupants end up dying due to the amount of time in it. I believe all three have one protagonist who survives and makes it outside of the cube. That scene is generally weird – almost as though they are walking into a void in some respects.

So, the third movie, Cube Zero, has as one of the protagonists, a woman who is trying to reunite with her daughter. So I’m thinking you may have seen that movie and/or Hypercube, which has a weird ending where some of the characters die in a manner that could be construed as being sucked into space.

I can't recall anything about a comb though.

Comment: I don't think cube was a novel?