# Old Science fiction novel about a huge cube people were living in

Tags: story-identification

This will be a hard one. 
In the 90's I remember reading a book about a huge cube people were living in.
I remember that there were huge rooms  where different "groups of people" were living, connected by elevators that were traveling for days.

Another particular detail is that the rooms were cleared by fire when there was nobody left, and that the meat was grown in labs.

And because I was a teen at that time, I clearly remember a scene describing a blow job between the two main caracters....

The details are quite vague but I remember that there was a man and a woman running from something and that at least the woman manged to get inside one of the elevators and reach another room.

I remeber that the book was quite old when I was reading it, so the novel could be from the 70's.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hmm?; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128494/book-about-a-cube-prison-that-turns-out-to-be-a-spaceship

Comment: The title says "Old" but the body says "the 90's". A book from the 1990s would hardly be "old" so I guess you mean the 1890s?

Comment: @user14111 A book from roughly 25 years ago is old. That there are much older books from centuries ago does not make the 25 year-old book "new," except by comparison, and this book is not being compared to any others in this question.

Comment: @Steve-O A 25-year-old dog or cat is old. A 25-year-old human or book is not old.

Comment: Guys, I was reading the book in the 90's, but I remember the book itself was in a bad shape, that's why I think it could be older than that... 70's maybe ,,,,,

Comment: @user14111: "A 25-year-old human or book is not old." They both are if you ask a 12 year old for his opinion. "Old" is subjective.

Comment: Remind me not to ask a 12 year old for his opinion.

Comment: @Valorum... it's published in 2010, sound similar... I don't remember being a prison ...

Answer (score 2):

Could you be thinking of ["The World Inside"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Inside) by Robert Silverberg?  It was published in 1971, which matches your description.  People do live in very large multi-story residential blocks (the wikipedia article says 1,000 stories).

Not all of your description sounds familiar to me ("meat grown in labs" rings no bells) but it's been quite a while since I read it so I have probably forgotten some incidental details.

I do not remember any explicit sex scenes but there was definitely sex-related content.  In fact the wikipedia article says it is considered a capital crime to refuse an invitation for sex.